# Scala/Chisel Data to be connected must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type

Tags: scala, chisel

im trying to design the following Ripple Carry Adder made of Fulladers. I tried a lot so far, but I'm struggling with Chisel Syntax. Could someone help me out and point out what I'm doing wrong? This is my Code below:

```
class RcaAdder(val n:Int) extends Module {
 val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val a    = Input(UInt(n.W))
  val b    = Input(UInt(n.W))
  val cin  = Input(UInt(1.W))
  val sum  = Output(UInt(n.W))
  val cout = Output(UInt(1.W))
 })


 //Create FullAdders
 val fadder = Seq.tabulate(n) {
   x => Module(new FullAdder())
 }

 //Setup
 val summ = chisel3.Vec(n, Bool())
 val carry = chisel3.Vec(n+1, UInt(1.W))
 carry(0) := io.cin

 //Do the wiring
 for(inx <- 0 to n){

   fadder(inx).io.a := io.a(inx)
   fadder(inx).io.b := io.b(inx)
   fadder(inx).io.cin := io.cin
   carry(inx+1) := fadder(inx).io.cout
   summ(inx) := fadder(inx).io.sum
 }

 io.sum := summ.asUInt()
 io.cout := carry(n+1)

}
```

This is the error:

```
data to be connected 'UInt<1>' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type
    at rca.RcaAdder.<init>(RcaAdder.scala:40)
    RcaAdder.scala:40
```

Tried wrapping carry or summ in Wire() or IO(), but that didn't help. :(

Any ideas? Really struggling here.

Comment: I know you said you tried Wire, but did you try it like `Wire(Vec(n , Bool()))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| Stevo | is right about the Wire wrapper being necessary but there are a couple of other errors.

- Add `Wire` wrapper to `summ` and `carry`
- Your for statement should use `until` and not `to`
- Should be `io.cout := carry(n)` not `n+1`

The following code should work.

```
class RcaAdder(val n:Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a    = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val b    = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val cin  = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val sum  = Output(UInt(n.W))
    val cout = Output(UInt(1.W))
  })


  //Create FullAdders
  val fadder = Seq.tabulate(n) {
    x => Module(new FullAdder())
  }

  //Setup
  val summ = Wire(chisel3.Vec(n, Bool()))
  val carry = Wire(chisel3.Vec(n+1, UInt(1.W)))
  carry(0) := io.cin

  //Do the wiring
  for(inx <- 0 until n){

    fadder(inx).io.a := io.a(inx)
    fadder(inx).io.b := io.b(inx)
    fadder(inx).io.cin := io.cin
    carry(inx+1) := fadder(inx).io.cout
    summ(inx) := fadder(inx).io.sum
  }

  io.sum := summ.asUInt()
  io.cout := carry(n)

}
```

Your problem here is good case for using `foldLeft` over `for` IMO as it reduces the chances of making indexing errors.